# How do I use the "head" command in unix for a specified directory?

Tags: bash, shell, unix, command-line, command

I am making a bash script command. At the moment the head command only displays the first "x number" of lines for all the files in the current directory.

How do I get it to display the "x number" of lines of all files in a different specified directory. So without me having to cd into a different directory.

Comment: have you tried `head path/to/dir/*` ?

Comment: @user2599522 yes thanks a lot that works. Now how would i specify an argument so that it can display the head of a specific filename.

Comment: this smells like homework :p. Have you tried `head path/to/file` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
head "path_to_dir"/* -n x
```

where:

**head** is the command in question

**"path_to_dir"/*** passes head "all files in dir"

**-n x** tells head to return the first x lines of each file it encounters

Comment: how would i do it for a specific file name in that directory

Comment: replace the * with that filename

Answer (score 2):

You can also use find command:

```
find DIR -type f -exec head -n X {} \;
```